# How to format strings in classes using attributes?

Tags: python, oop

I want to format an attribute-string of a class with another attribute of the same class like this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.full_name = 'name, {}'.format(self.name)

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.full_name)

my_object = Test()
my_object.name = 'my_object'

my_object.print_name()
```

Now it should print 'name, my_object'
But it prints 'name, None'

What to do that the string formats with the assigned value of the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `full_name` as a `property` so that you can add some more logic to it:

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return f'name, {self.name}'

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.full_name)


my_object = Test()
my_object.name = 'my_object'

my_object.print_name()
```

Resources:

- [`property` function (built-in)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)

Comment: `print_name()` is quite useless there though.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I guess, but it is the same useful as in the OP's code, for example, they also could just use `print(self.full_name)` or the `print_name` function could be the one that creates this string or it could be created using `__str__` or sth else, but as for learning this is fine, after all their question was about _formatting strings using attributes_